# CanExecute for KeyBindings to control

Tags: wpf, command, key-bindings, documentviewer

I have a reportViewer with default toolbar button for decrease zoom binded to command `NavigationCommands.DecreaseZoom`. I want to disable it in some situation so i bind `CanExecute` method to return false for that command which works perfectly fine and disable the button as expected. But, still zoom out works if i use shortcut key `"Ctrl + Subtract key"`. I tried to set `KeyBinding` to the same command assuming CanExecute will work but it doesn't. Since, CanExecute is not provided in KeyBinding. Can someone suggest how can i disable KeyGesture "Ctrl -" for some situation(logic in CanExecute) and not permanently.

Relevant code -

```
<DocumentViewer Name="documentViewer1"
                        Margin="0,0,0,30"
                        Style="{DynamicResource DocumentViewerStyle1}">
   <DocumentViewer.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="NavigationCommands.DecreaseZoom"
                        CanExecute="DecreaseZoom_CanExecute" />
   </DocumentViewer.CommandBindings>
   <DocumentViewer.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Command="NavigationCommands.DecreaseZoom"
                    Key="OemMinus"
                    Modifiers="Control" />
    </DocumentViewer.InputBindings>
</DocumentViewer>
```

Code behind -

```
private void DecreaseZoom_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if (((DocumentViewer)e.Source).PageViews.Count >= 3)
   {
       e.CanExecute = false;
       e.ContinueRouting = false;
       e.Handled = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Can we see the code where you are creating your command for DecreaseZoom.

Comment: DecreaseZoom is NavigationCommand, not my custom command..

Comment: Oh, I apologize, I have not been working much with the build in commands so I did not recognize the use of setting the CanExecute in the CommandBinding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem extending DocumentViewer and overriding method OnDecreaseZoomCommand. I tried using Custom Command but its event handler is not getting hit in case i use shortcut key "Ctrl -". But this works for me -

```
public class ExtendedDocumentViewer : DocumentViewer
{
   protected override void OnDecreaseZoomCommand()
   {
      if (PageViews.Count < 3)
      {
         base.OnDecreaseZoomCommand();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either create your custom command for this or you can create your own InputGesture, and override its behavior,

```
 <KeyBinding.Gesture>
   <CustomInputGesture/>
 </KeyBinding.Gesture>
```

Comment: Even creating my CustomCommand and using CustomInputGesture doesn't work for Shortcut key "Ctrl -"